# Computing Smith normal form of a matrix with $\bmod p$ coefficients

Tags: matrix, polynomials, finite-fields

I would like to compute the Smith normal form of a matrix with coefficients in $GF(p)$.  In particular, I am interested in $GF(2)$.  I have used the [Smith normal form packages](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/682) for integer and polynomial matrices before.  Can these be adapted to work for matrices with finite field coefficients?  Is there another way to compute the Smith normal forms $\bmod p$ in *Mathematica*?

Comment: A small example input would be helpful.

Comment: Since this has bubbled back to the surface, I think today what I might try is this. Augment beneath the matrix with `2*IdentityMatrix[ncols]`, to the right with `2*IdentityMatrix[nrows]`, and the bottom right with zeros of dimension `ncols` x `nrows`. Then do `SmithDecomposition`. Last, remove excess (this might take some figuring out though).

Comment: I guess Daniel is suggesting something like `SmithDecomposition[ArrayFlatten[{{mat, 2 IdentityMatrix[nrows]}, {2 IdentityMatrix[ncols], 0}}]]`.

Comment: What @J.M... said. If I knew how to use `ArrayFlatten`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is some code based on functionality in the development version of Mathematica.

```
moduleGroebnerBasis[polys_, p_, vars_, cvars_, opts___] := 
 Catch[Module[{newpols, rels, len = Length[cvars], gb, j, k, rul}, 
   If[! FreeQ[polys, $Failed], Throw[$Failed]];
   rels = Flatten[Table[cvars[[j]]*cvars[[k]], {j, len}, {k, j, len}]];
   newpols = Join[polys, rels];
   Quiet[gb = 
     GroebnerBasis[newpols, Join[cvars, vars], opts, Modulus -> p]];
   If[Head[gb] === GroebnerBasis, Throw[$Failed]];
   rul = Map[(# -> {}) &, rels];
   gb = Flatten[gb /. rul];
   Collect[gb, cvars]]]

groebnerHNF[omat_?MatrixQ, p_, var_] := 
 Catch[Module[{mat, nr, nc, v, newvars, generators, mgb, 
    res}, {nr, nc} = Dimensions[omat];
   mat = Join[omat, IdentityMatrix[nr], 2];
   newvars = Array[v, nr + nc];
   generators = mat.newvars;
   mgb = moduleGroebnerBasis[generators, p, {var}, newvars];
   If[! FreeQ[mgb, $Failed] || Length[mgb] =!= nr, Throw[$Failed]];
   res = Outer[D, Reverse[mgb], newvars];
   {res[[All, 1 ;; nc]], res[[All, nc + 1 ;; -1]]}]]

diagonalMatrixQ[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 Catch[Do[If[i == j, Continue[], 
     If[mat[[i, j]] =!= 0, Throw[False]]];, {i, Length[mat]}, {j, 
    Length[mat[[1]]]}];
  Throw[True]]

diagonalize[mat_, p_, var_] := 
 Catch[Module[{hnf = mat, nr = Length[mat], nc = Length[mat[[1]]], 
    umat, vmat, tmpu, tmpv, approx = Precision[mat] =!= Infinity}, 
   umat = IdentityMatrix[nr];
   vmat = IdentityMatrix[nc];
   While[Not[diagonalMatrixQ[hnf]], hnf = groebnerHNF[hnf, p, var];
    If[! FreeQ[hnf, $Failed], Throw[$Failed]];
    {hnf, tmpu} = hnf;
    umat = PolynomialMod[Dot[tmpu, umat], p];
    hnf = groebnerHNF[Transpose[hnf], p, var];
    If[! FreeQ[hnf, $Failed], Throw[$Failed]];
    {hnf, tmpv} = hnf;
    vmat = PolynomialMod[Dot[vmat, Transpose[tmpv]], p];
    hnf = Transpose[hnf];];
   {umat, hnf, vmat}]]

dividesQ[p1_, p2_, p_, var_] := Catch[Module[{quo, rem},
   If[FreeQ[{p1, p2}, var], Throw[True]];
   {quo, rem} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[p2, p1, var, Modulus -> p];
   rem === 0]]

smithDecompositionGroebner[mat_, p_, var_] := 
 Catch[Module[{snf, uu, dd, vv, diags, gcd, col = 0, dim, tmpu, tmpv},
    snf = diagonalize[mat, p, var];
   If[! FreeQ[snf, $Failed], Throw[$Failed]];
   {uu, dd, vv} = snf;
   diags = Select[Flatten[dd], Not[TrueQ[# == 0]] &];
   dim = Length[diags];
   While[col + 1 < dim, col++;
    If[dividesQ[diags[[col]], 
      PolynomialGCD[Apply[Sequence, Drop[diags, col]], Modulus -> p], 
      p, var], Continue[]];
    vv = Transpose[vv];
    Do[dd[[j, col]] = diags[[j]];
     vv[[col]] = PolynomialMod[vv[[col]] + vv[[j]], p], {j, col + 1, 
      dim}];
    vv = Transpose[vv];
    snf = diagonalize[dd, p, var];
    If[! FreeQ[snf, $Failed], Throw[$Failed]];
    {tmpu, dd, tmpv} = snf;
    uu = PolynomialMod[tmpu.uu, p];
    vv = PolynomialMod[vv.tmpv, p];
    diags = Select[Flatten[dd], Not[TrueQ[# == 0]] &];];
   {uu, dd, vv}]]
```

Brief example:

```
t = {{(1 + s) (3 + s), 0, 0}, {(1 + s) (3 + s), 1 + s, 0}, {0,
     1 + s, (1 + s) (4 + s)}};

smithDecompositionGroebner[t, 13, s]

(* Out[80]= {{{0, 12, 1}, {12, 2, 12}, {12, 10 + 12 s, 3 + s}}, {{1 + s, 
   0, 0}, {0, 1 + s, 0}, {0, 0, 12 + 6 s + 8 s^2 + s^3}}, {{1, 0, 
   9 + 12 s}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 10 + 12 s}}} *)
```

A perfectly reasonable question might be "Does it work correctly?" My response would be "Probably". The basic approach to the Hermite decomposition is described [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259235706_Applications_of_strong_Grobner_bases_over_Euclidean_domains?ev=prf_pub) (I seem to be referring to this quite a bit today).

Comment: Daniel, your knowledge of "what has already been done" seems to be amazing.

Comment: @Jacob Akkerboom It was easy enough in this case, since it involved (mostly) code I had written. (I'm not a Control Theorist, but sometimes I portray one in my spare time.)

Comment: I was just wondering why there is still no build-in function in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatrixPredicates.html  for the function you wrote above `diagonalMatrixQ`? Should not this predict be also a build-in function in Mathematica?

Comment: @Nasser Hard for me to say whether it warrants built-in status. I can say it's not a predicate I've used often myself. But maybe others do, and frequently write their own.